# Converting single excel workbook with multiple sheets into multiple excel workbooks with multiple sheets with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, logic

I currently have an excel workbook that has 100 tabs. The name are like this, `DHA`, `HHD`, `UAF`,...

I have another excel file that has a table that looks like this,

```
name category
DHA  cat1
HHD  cat1
UAF  cat2
...
```

I have 10 categories, each category could have any number of names.

I want to create 10 excel sheets with the sheets as the names, so for example, `cat1.xlsx` would have tabs `DHA` and `HHD`, `cat2.xlsx` would have `UAF` etc as its sheets.

Here is the code that I have tried so far,

```
categoryNames = pd.read_excel('categories.xlsx', sheet_name='categories')

savepath = fr"/Users/xxx/Documents/"
for idx,row in categoryNames.iterrows():
    filepath = os.path.join(savepath,f'{row[1]}.xlsx') #this will make the filename the category number
    print(filepath)
    if os.path.exists(filepath):
        print('appending')
        book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filepath, engine = 'xlsxwriter')
        writer.book = book
        print(row[0])
        fullexcel[row[0]].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=row[0],index=False)
        writer.save()
        writer.close()
    else:
        print('creating')
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filepath, engine = 'xlsxwriter')
        print(row[0])
        fullexcel[row[0]].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=row[0],index=False)
        writer.save()
        writer.close()
```

The files get saved, but they seem to be corrupted, when I try to open them, I can see the data but it doesn't load into pandas again. I get the error, `ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined,` even though I have chosen xlsxwriter or openpyxl.

What is the correct way to create files in this manner and append them as new sheets if the files already exist?

Comment: it could be you are using openpyxl to read a file and writing using the pandas excelwriter.  what happens if you change engine = 'xlsxwriter' to engine = 'openpyxl'? Or use openpyxl to write the information?

Comment: Also, Pandas documentation recommends to use pandas.ExcelWriter "as a context manager; otherwise, call close() to save and close any opened file handles.", like this for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67965468/11246056